# Handle Parse to Float, when input is Null

Tags: c#

I want to parse a string to float. And when the string is null it will pass 0 (as a float valule).

I was doing the parse like this :

```
aeVehicle.MSRP = float.Parse((drInvetory["MSRP"] ?? "0").ToString());
```

Which gave errors :

```
ERROR MESSAGE : Input string was not in a correct format.
ERROR SOURCE :    at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseSingle(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.Single.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Single.Parse(String s)
```

Please suggest the best way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `drInvetory["MSRP"]` comes from a `DataRow`, the null coalescing operator will not evaluate to true when compared to `DBNull`, thus the float parse will fail. You can compare for `DBNull.Value`, or use `float.TryParse()`.

**From Original Code**

```
aeVehicle.MSRP = float.Parse(drInvetory["MSRP"] == DBNull.Value ? "0" : drInvetory["MSRP"].ToString());
```

Personally, I would check for `DBNull` and then cast to a float (or unbox to exact type, then cast). This saves a comparatively expensive string parse.

**Better**

```
aeVehicle.MSRP = drInvetory["MSRP"] == DBNull.Value ? default( float ) : 
(float)drInvetory["MSRP"];
```

SQL-CLR type mapping: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx
See also: [Difference between decimal, float and double in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c)

Comment: Never knew this..Yes..it comes from a DataRow

Comment: @Tim Medora..i double checked this..you are right..you taught me a great thing today..Thanks

Comment: From question seems that drInvetory["MSRP"] returns string. If so this will throw a exception: (float)drInvetory["MSRP"]. Better to use Convert.ToSingle()

Comment: @Petar no, it returns `object`. `object` can be null-coalesced with `string` - the result is an `object` expression; then the existing code calls `.ToString()` for the `Parse`. With that information, we can't really make any presumptions about what `drInvetory["MSRP"]` actually *is*. If it is actually a boxed `float`, then I agree with the "Better". If it is actually a string that *happens to have a numeric-looking value*, then `Parse`.

Comment: "MSRP" field is "Money" type in sql server.
I fetch this and stores in a DataTable.

Comment: In that case, you may want to use `decimal` (see the link I added to the answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
float f = 0f;
string s = (drInvetory["MSRP"] ?? "0").ToString();
if (s != null) {
    f = float.Parse(s, ...
}
```

Comment: `0.0` is a `double`; `0f` would be better, or just `0`.

Comment: Thanks - been in Java land today (no excuse, 0.0 is double in java too).

Comment: Why ToString() ? It is already a string. And s cannot be null, so if seems not necessary. If drInvetory["MSRP"] is not a string this will not compile I think.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the the TryParse :

```
    float num = 0;
    float.TryParse(s, out num);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might caused by unexpected comma in your string. Try to throw away the comma first.

Answer (score 0):

```
float result = 0;
float.TryParse(drInvetory["MSRP"], out result);
aeVehicle.MSRP = result;
```

This way, if the parse fails, then it will always fall-back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

another simple alternate is:

```
aeVehicle.MSRP = float.Parse("0" + drInvetory["MSRP"].ToString());
```

It will work only for positive numbers.
otherwise use Microsoft.VisualBasic.Val function which is the most convenient one.